# Why is facebook returning null email on validated users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, spring-social-facebook

i have a problem getting the email field from fb api call for some of the users. I can confirm i tested it with verified real user's mails. For some of them i get the email field but for others i get null.
I'm standard js to get the access token and i'm using spring artefact:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

here is FE code:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
            if(response.authResponse.accessToken) {
                // submit token to server
                facebookSuccess(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
        }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});


   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '1567056303561905',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.5'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Here is server code:

```
Facebook fb = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User fbUser = fb.userOperations().getUserProfile();
```

fbUser.getEmail();// returns null

Comment: Ask for the email field.

Comment: I did ask for the field in my javascript call. Also i tried using the fb graph api explorer with a valid token which also included email field but the graph api didn't return it.

Comment: And those users did grant your app the `email` permission? (Check by requesting `/me/permissions` using their access token.) / Even if the user grants permission and the email address is verified, there are some edge cases where due to privacy settings the API still won’t return it. Since not every user even has an email on file with Facebook (f.e. if they registered using only their mobile), you need to implement a step for them to input it themselves, if your app really _needs_ an email address.

Comment: Hi, yes, they did. Please see the code {scope: 'public_profile,email'}.

Comment: It is possible that even if the user has granted the permission for email, in his account settings, he has set his email to be shared with no one. In that case, email will be null.